# sound not working in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, motherboard

I have upgraded my machine a couple of times, from ubuntu 16, to kubuntu 16 then 18 and now 19.04 & finally 19.10. what should i do from here?

however the sound is not working on my machine..

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H57 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
03:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6315 Series Firewire Controller (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

Comment: Can you please take a screenshot of `alsamixer`?

Comment: Assuming your sound hardware is detected and you see no issues with `sudo lshw -C sound` (list-hardware of class=sound),  I'd try `pavucontrol` (pulse audio volume control); it's fixed all my problems.  Check it's not muted, click profile off & back on in configuration tab, audio's going to wanted speakers etc...

Comment: @guiverc it just hangs on etablising connection to paulse audio ... please wait

Comment: can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problems.  Sound worked ok up to Ubuntu 19.10, then the selected sound device is a faked one, and no sounds from pulsaudio.

I tried this command, which help each time I do login, but it is only a temporary solution.  I want a permanent solution too.

The command is `sudo alsa force-reload`

But yes, also interested of a permanent solution.